# variable inside the array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm a total newbie in PHP and I'm trying to insert a variable inside the array but it's not working...

Here is the code:

```
$data     = $RytvAPI->validateConfiguration(
array(
 'relation' => 'posttitle',
 'max'      => '1',
 'width'    => 450,
 'height'   => 250,
 'lang'     => 'en',
 'region'   => 'us',
 'class'    => 'spacing-10',
 'preview'  => true    
 )
);
```

I want to replace

```
'relation' => 'posttitle',
```

with

```
'relation' => $resultd,
```

Where `$resultd` is  a short PHP code

```
$my_title = wp_title('', false);
$data3 = "-";
$cat_name = $cat->cat_name;
$resultd = $cat_name.$data3.$my_title;
```

Comment: `'relation' => $resultd` is correct . How did you test it and said not working?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after $resultd is set.

Try this code.

```
$valConfig = array(
 'relation' => 'posttitle',
 'max'      => '1',
 'width'    => 450,
 'height'   => 250,
 'lang'     => 'en',
 'region'   => 'us',
 'class'    => 'spacing-10',
 'preview'  => true

);

$my_title = wp_title('', false);
$data3 = "-";
$cat_name = $cat->cat_name;
$resultd = $cat_name.$data3.$my_title;

$valConfig['relation'] = $resultd;

 $data     = $RytvAPI->validateConfiguration($valConfig);
```